# Client ID authentication no longer works with Kafka API

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, message-hub

Using the Message Hub Kafka interface, I've found that my Bluemix app that was using client.id authentication is getting connections refused by the Kafka brokers. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Message Hub service is switching off client.id authentication in mid-January 2016. It is replaced by SASL authentication. Documentation on authenticating with the service using SASL can be found in the documentation:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html#messagehub063
https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2016/01/25/message-hub-beta-plan-ending/

A Java sample using the Message Hub SASL login library can be found at:
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-samples

SASL is currently available on both port 9093 and 9094 for a grace period, after which 9094 will be switched off. The timeline for this change is also available in the Message Hub docs, as linked above.